# Column toggle not working when append the table rows dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, html-table

In  jQuery mobile v 1.4.5 i used table rows append dynamically with column toggle but it does not work for the rows which are dynamically generated.

```
<table id="tab" data-role="table" data-mode="columntoggle" class="ui-responsive">
    <tbody id="tb" >
        <thead id="th">
            <tr id="tr1">
                <th>First</th>
                <th data-priority="1">Second</th>
                <th data-priority="2">third</th>
            </tr>

        </thead>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/txej8qhj/1/)  what I tried.

I referred this jQuery mobile [document](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/examples/tables/columntoggle-refresh.html#&ui-state=dialog).

**Note:** I want to insert the table rows at the top of the previous rows (dynamically added rows that why I used **"after"** property).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Edited:

New link is the below to locate created new row on the top of the table

### http://jsfiddle.net/txej8qhj/6/

---

The below link works fine;

http://jsfiddle.net/txej8qhj/3/

Probably you too know. Sometimes we may overlook somethings. You should separate the `thead` and `tbody` element. Actually `thead` element first comes in a table like the below;

```
<table>
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Check the below link out to use as guide;

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/table-column-toggle/#&ui-state=dialog

Comment: your answer seems work but i need to add the new row at the top of the table ..thats why i use after property..

Comment: i need one more help....i need this table row with in UI ..http://jsfiddle.net/vvnpL3vw/3/

Comment: see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/txej8qhj/8/ i don't want any static table rows inside table body

Comment: i need to show all th table values within the UI or make that part only scrollable..

Comment: i managed to append the table row at the top of the table body without static rows in table body..now i want the table should be responsive..

Comment: Could you tell me, whether your aim is adding table header(column) dynamically and showing/hiding those columns?

Comment: leave it that hiding and showing columns...now want to that table should be responsive...

Comment: Me too use jQuery Mobile with my apps. But if the issue responsive table there are some options like https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/   and http://fooplugins.com/footable/demos/showcase.htm . I chose footable. But both of them are good. Actually the most famous tool among them is datatables..

Answer (score 2):

You need to call *refresh* and trigger *create* functions on the table element.

Please, try the below:

```
 $("#tr1").after(newrow);
 $('#tab').table("refresh").trigger("create");
```